# How do I learn the time when the alarm has been set on the alarm app of android?

Tags: android, alarm

I am making an app which needs the time at which the alarm has been set on the alarm app of an Android phone, as well as the time that the alarm has been set for.

That is, if I set the alarm for 8.00 AM at 2.00 AM, then I want both 2.00 AM and 8.00 AM.

How do I get this data? I want to use the standard alarm app that comes on Android phones.

Comment: You do realize that quite a few people use non-default alarm clocks, due to the manufacturer, or self choice? And every alarm clock, if they even provide the information, would probably be in a different format?

Comment: I can probably figure out how to handle different formats of the time once I have those two times with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't because alarm application is not part of the Android. It just **ships** with Android and this makes huge difference. And since many vendors customize shipped version of Android, application shipped varies and if you get two "Android devices" these may significantly vary in lists of available built-in applications (i.e. see stock Nexus vs something from HTC).

But if you still insist you need to dig in **private** data of particular application (like alarm app), then you still cannot do that unless device is rooted, as every application is sandboxed and by default it is not allowed to access other apps' data.

Comment: So you're saying the best bet would be to build an alarm into my app?

Comment: @uttara_shekar: Either that, or find some existing third-party alarm app, available from the Play Store, that offers a richer API, and integrate with it.

Comment: @uttara_shekar it might be the best approach, especially it shall be rather trivial and would allow you to keep full control on this. Using 3rd party alarm may not be welcomed by your users - some may not like that dependency - so evaluate all pro/cons and pick what suits you best.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I am trying to build an alarm into my app. I think this is the easiest approach. Will get back if I have more queries. But thank you. :)

Comment: No wait, it probably isnt the easiest approach. Sigh, do you know how to build a customized alarm app?

Comment: the same way you build any other app. You create UI to let user set date or time (or both) for alarm, you use AlarmManager to "plant" your alarm, you create BroadcastReceiver to be able to be notified by AlarmManager that the alarm occurred, you react on the event and do what you want. Googling for "Android AlarmManager Tutorial" should give you good start

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get this data?

Sorry, but there is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

> I want to use the standard alarm app that comes on Android phones.

There is more than one such app. Device manufacturers can and do replace the AOSP alarm clock app with their own.

Comment: Are you saying I have absolutely no way of knowing the time at which a user sets the alarm?

Comment: @uttara_shekar: You are welcome to ask them what time they set an alarm for. They may not give you the right answer, they may not have set an alarm, or they may have set several alarms.